# Indentation Error with python: Indented block

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> for link in soup.find_all('a'):
... print link
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print link
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to better understand the downvotes and learn to improve your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

The correct indentation should be:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link)
```

Try this snippet to understand the need for indentation

```
for x in range(3):
    print("Inside the loop", x)

print("Outside the loop, this print is run only once")
```

This notion is well explained in the [beginning of Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming):

> The *body* of the loop is *indented*: indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements. At the interactive prompt, you have to type a tab or space(s) for each indented line. In practice you will prepare more complicated input for Python with a text editor; all decent text editors have an auto-indent facility. When a compound statement is entered interactively, it must be followed by a blank line to indicate completion (since the parser cannot guess when you have typed the last line). Note that each line within a basic block must be indented by the same amount.

Comment: May I know why is there "IndentationError: expected an indented block"?

Comment: Because you did not indent your print. Python uses indentation to determine which instructions are in your loop and which are outside

Comment: Sorry Antwane, I don't get what you mean. Do you have any links or examples for me to understand it better?

Comment: I've edited my answer to link to the correct text in python docs

Comment: I get it now, but when I retry it shows "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(link)?"

Comment: You tagged your question with `Python2.7`. In python 2, print parenthesis are optional. If you run your code with Python 3 interpreter, parenthesis are mandatory.